# Passing a $scope variable into $state.href?

Tags: angularjs, parameters, scope, href, state

Below is a function in my controller

```
$scope.getUrl = function() {
   $state.href('newState', 
    {randomId: $scope.randomId, anotherOne: $scope.anotherOne}
   );
};
```

The above function is being called in the template like so (but not working of course):

```
<div ng-href="{{getUrl()}}">
```

Is there a way to pass $scope variable's from my controller into the $state.href?

Any feedback is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

return your value from `getUrl()`

```
$scope.getUrl = function() {
   return $state.href('newState', 
      {randomId: $scope.randomId, anotherOne: $scope.anotherOne}
   );
};
```